# Keeping original sender in inter-contract call

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I have a token contract (let's say it `TC`) and creating a contract `Wallet`. Now, is it possible for a user to call `Wallet`'s entrypoint `deposit` which will do an inter-contract call to `TC`'s `transfer` entrypoint to transfer some of the user's token to the `Wallet`? Since `TC` will check that the sender is the owner of those tokens, it'll require keeping the sender the same when doing the inter-contract call.

Answer (score 1):

[SENDER](https://tezos.gitlab.io/michelson-reference/#instr-SENDER) always points to the caller's address.

[SOURCE](https://tezos.gitlab.io/michelson-reference/#instr-SOURCE) points to the implicit account that initiated the current transaction.

[image]

SmartPY example: https://smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmevNhUmzeDBzi5uYyxcWdMphrqurJz8TGiVQpeJRgKu58&k=1adea9375ecba75eaab6

Comment: Since I can't change the token contract, any suggestion to implement the `Wallet` contract? Or the user has to explicitly call the transfer entypoint everytime to transfer tokens to the `Wallet` (even then how will my `Wallet` know that this user transferred those tokens)?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at a feature called "tickets". An application of tickets is to use them as authentication tokens that can be transmitted across contract call chains.